# how to make group by optional in zend framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

i have a `fetchAll` function in zend:

```
public function fetchAll($where = 1, $order = null, $limit = null, $group = null, array $fields = null)
{
    $where = (null == $where) ? 1 : $where;


    $fields = (!isset($fields)) ? '*' : $fields;

    $select = $this->db->select()
                       ->from("table", $fields)
                       ->where($where)
                       ->order($order)
                       ->group($group)
                       ->limit($limit, $offset);
    echo $select; exit;
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($select);
    return $this->getResultObjects($result);
}
```

and i can call this function `$this->fetchAll('field = 1', null, 10)`;

i can `$order to null` and the query will work just fine but not the `$group` for some reason.

How can i make it so that the group is optional and goes in only if i sat it to something?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods are chained so you can split it up:

```
$select = $this->db->select()
  ->from("table", $fields)
  ->where($where);
  ->order($order)
  ->limit($limit, $offset);

if ($group) { 
  $select->group($group);
}

$result = $this->db->fetchAll($select);
return $this->getResultObjects($result);
```

Every method in the chain (`from`, `where`, `order`, etc) returns an instance of `Zend_Db_Select`. So every time you call one of those methods you can immediately follow it up with another method call from that same class.

These code blocks are identical:

```
// With chaining

$select = $this->db->select()
  ->from("table", $fields)
  ->where($where);
  ->order($order)
  ->limit($limit, $offset);

// No chaining

$select = $this->db->select();
$select = $select->from("table", $fields);
$select = $select->where($where);
$select = $select->order($order);
$select = $select->limit($limit, $offset);
```

You can see why chaining is preferred. Note: the assignment (`$select =`) is mostly superflous in the non-chain example, I only left it in to show the clunkyness.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$select = $this->db->select()
                   ->from("table", $fields)
                   ->where($where)
                   ->order($order)
                   ->limit($limit, $offset);

if(!empty($group)){
    $select->group($group)
}
```

This works because doctrine won't execute your query into you call execute. So until then you can keep building the query.

Doh, I thought your question was regarding Doctrine. But yeah apparently it works in a similar fashion with ZendDb. See Mike B's answer.